# Mahout : output file giving error in Hadoop

Tags: hadoop, mahout

I am getting the following error while running Mahout on Hadoop.

Command:

```
 mahout recommenditembased -s SIMILARITY_LOGLIKELIHOOD -i /user/inp -o /user/op --numRecommendations 5
```

Error :

```
Running on hadoop, using /usr/local/hadoop/bin/hadoop and HADOOP_CONF_DIR=
MAHOUT-JOB: /opt/apache-mahout-distribution- 0.11.0/examples/target/mahout-examples-0.11.0-job.jar
15/11/05 17:52:29 INFO AbstractJob: Command line arguments: {--booleanData=[false], --endPhase=[2147483647], --input=[/user/inp], --maxPrefsInItemSimilarity=[500], --maxPrefsPerUser=[10], --maxSimilaritiesPerItem=[100], --minPrefsPerUser=[1], --numRecommendations=[5], --output=[/user/], --similarityClassname=[SIMILARITY_LOGLIKELIHOOD], --startPhase=[0], --tempDir=[temp]}
15/11/05 17:52:29 INFO AbstractJob: Command line arguments: {--booleanData=[false], --endPhase=[2147483647], --input=[/user/inp], --minPrefsPerUser=[1], --output=[temp/preparePreferenceMatrix], --ratingShift=[0.0], --startPhase=[0], --tempDir=[temp]}
15/11/05 17:52:30 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
15/11/05 17:52:30 INFO deprecation: mapred.input.dir is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.input.fileinputformat.inputdir
15/11/05 17:52:30 INFO deprecation: mapred.compress.map.output is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.map.output.compress
15/11/05 17:52:30 INFO deprecation: mapred.output.dir is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.output.fileoutputformat.outputdir
15/11/05 17:52:30 INFO deprecation: session.id is deprecated. Instead, use dfs.metrics.session-id
15/11/05 17:52:30 INFO JvmMetrics: Initializing JVM Metrics with processName=JobTracker, sessionId=
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileAlreadyExistsException: Output directory temp/preparePreferenceMatrix/itemIDIndex already exists
```

But I couldn't find any output folder created :

```
hadoop fs -ls /
15/11/05 17:55:40 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native- hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
Found 1 items
drwxr-xr-x   - hduser supergroup          0 2015-11-05 17:47 /user
```

How to solve this ?

Mahout Version :0.11.0

Comment: Like the message said, you need to remove the directory from HDFS first then run the script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was facing same issue. Found solution to this.

Mahout gives error if output file directory or tempDir already exists. So first delete and then execute command. Also use custom `--tempDir` option and set temporary directory for output generation. Otherwise it will generate `temp` folder at location where you are executing command. If you don't want to have custom tempDir then delete `temp/` directory before you are executing command.

```
rm -rf /user/op /tmp/mahout/ && mahout recommenditembased -s SIMILARITY_LOGLIKELIHOOD -i /user/inp -o /user/op --tempDir /tmp/mahout/ --numRecommendations 5
```

Comment: I couldn't find the location where it is creating the `temp/` directory. I went with the `--tempDir` flag solution and that worked for me. Thanks!